# Git branching strategy for Agile project

Tags: git, branch

I have a project that is located in Git Stash Repository. The code will be deployed in four environments(Dev, Test, Stage and Prod). We follow Agile methodology. So dev team works for both Release activities and Non Release( Future Release) activities. I have to create branches based on this requirement. Below is my plan.

Three stable branches: master, release and develop.

master is the default branch. develop will be created from master. release will be created from develop

feature branches --> they will be created from develop. each developer has one feature branch and they merge the code into develop branch once done. so dev environment deployment will happen from develop branch.

if changes need to go Test environment, we have two ways here. one is merge the develop branch with release branch( Test environment deployment will happen from release branch). We can not implement this since develop branch may have both release and non release changes.

another one way is merge the feature branches directly into release branch. so that each developers changes can be merged into release branch. I am not sure whether i can implement this method. Can someone please tell me if this way will work? is there any alternate way to handle this situation.

branching:

master branch---> develop branch --> release branch

develop branches --- feature branch1 | feature branch2 | feature branch3

---

deployments:

develop branch for --> dev deployments

release branch for --> test deployments

master branch for --> stage and prod deployments

I can not merge develop branch into release branch. Since develop branch has some non- release changes as well. I need only release changes on release branch. can feature branches be merged into release branch directly? What is the best approach here?

Comment: Have you read http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html ?

Comment: Thanks bunch..I took a look on it. Looks like they push the code every day. But we work based on agile sprint and releases

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it sounds to me like, you are very close to choosing [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Actually, if I'm not mistaken, this is already your base from the strategy, you describe. Which is great.

I'm hearing your main concern is, that you want a non-release "develop" branch, sort of like a "just trying stuff out, might not compile" environment/branch. Git flow indeed favours a "flow" towards production. I.e. once anything is merged from its feature-branch into the *develop*-branch, it's pretty much scheduled for next (non-emergency) release.

Git flow's suggestion on how to handle this, is to not merge a task/feature into *develop*, until it's probably ready enough to go into next staging/prod-release with maybe a few fixes. In git flow, you would always merge with non-fast forward (`git merge --no-ff FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME`) so that if you are getting near a staging/prod-release, and this feature cannot get ready, you would reverse-merge the (single) merge-commit, thus removing it from the *develop* or *release*-branch.

I suspect a longer discussion about this, but just to pitch, I see 2 possible ways to meet your ideas:

**1) Have 2 develop-branches**: one for development, *develop* branch, that will soon be sceduled for staging- and prod-release after some QA or whatever. And one for experimental stuff, that will go to a dev/test-environment (e.g. through continuous deployment). Let's call it *long-term-develop* (this is a bad and too long name imo, so make a better one, or your team will hate you :) ).

Thoughts:

- *develop* branch should often be merged into *long-term-develop* branch, to always keep it updated.
- You would probably need 2 develop-environments to test, 1 for each of the branches.
- **Danger**: branches created from *long-term-develop* that are (perhaps by mistake) merged into *develop* could drag more not-ready stuff into *develop* branch. Solution for this could be to 1) merge feature-branch as non-fastforward into *long-term-develop* and 2) cherry-pick merge this commit into *develop*. But this is error-prone and kind of complicated, and 1 wrong merge could screw up entire *develop* branch, polluting it with stuff not ready for staging/production.

**2) Have just 1 develop branch (as you suggest) and create release-branches from master**

This is probably by far the easiest way. It takes a little more effort from each developer, but is less error prone.

Procedure would be:

- At each beginning of a sprint/development-cycle, release-manager creates the next release-branch based off *master*. E.g. *release-sprint-42* which, when created, equals *master* branch.
- Developers create feature-branches with base from *develop*. They merge feature-branch to *develop* once it's ready for testing, et.c. Like you currently suggest.
- If feature is "correct" and working, the merge-commit that was created from merging the feature-branch into *develop* is cherry-picked with the `-m` option into *release-sprint-42*, e.g. `git cherry-pick -m 1 COMMIT_HASH`. Here it's really important to know, which parent you are picking (in my example parent 1. Develops should read and understand http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Thoughts:

- Danger could be, that a feature working in *develop* branch might not work in *release-sprint-42* branch, because of missing dependencies. This, thank God, is why we have staging environments and internal deadlines :)
- Cherry-picking is not the easiest thing to do. But definitely the best way to try to avoid dragging unwanted code through a merge into a wrong branch.

**Round up**

Which is the best choice for you, depends on how you are developing. If you have 2 tracks, like "daily support-stuff" and "my big feature scheduled for release this December", you might go for 2 branches. If the long-term development is not 1 but several things and an on-going thing (i.e. if you usually have a lot of tasks, that span over multiple sprints/cycles), I would go for option 2.

Ideally, though, I would per default recommend a strategy, where stuff is broken down into small enough pieces and sprints are big enough, that a task/feature usually can be concluded (i.e. merged and deployed!) within 1 sprint. But from experience I know, that wishful thinking seldomly can be implemented :)

1 last thing: I would REALLY really **really** encourage you to not have 1 release branch (perpetual), but to create a new release-branch for each sprint/cycle, like *release-sprint-42*, *release-sprint-43*, et.c. (whether you base it off develop-branch in ideal git flow or off master-branch in the second scenario, I've suggested). Having perpetual release-branches often in my experience leads to missing stuff, merge-problems and other badness. Other than that, *master* and *develop* should be perpetual-branches.

Looking forward to this discussion :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your thorough and clear information :) I really appreciate that. As you recommended, Having one develop branch would be fine. But my question was - can feature branches be directly merged into release branch or not? feature branches don't have any direct relationship with release branch since they are created from develop branch. In this case, will it work?

Creating release branches will not work in my case. all the builds should be automated till production. branch names should be stable forever. we can't create the branches for every release since it has manual work

Comment: Ok, I hear you: yes, you can merge the feature-branches into the (perpetual) release-branch. You can merge any branch into any branch - even code that has totally different origins. There's always a risk of conflicts, but if the only changes to release-branch are these merges, only the first merge could introduce a conflict. Just remember, cherry-picking will probably be needed, to avoid the risk of "dragging" unwanted changes into release-branch. Always check diffs before pushing/committing.

Comment: Also, if feature-branches are only merged to release-branch (and not into develop-branch), the release-branch should occasionally (often) be merged into develop to keep develop up-to-date. Or you can merge the feature-branches into both develop and release. Actually, if you want to cherry-pick a single commit (avoid multiple) you will either have to squash commits in feature-branch or (as I suggested in answer) first merge the feature-branch into develop (--no-ff) and then cherry-pick this exact merge/commit into the release-branch. It could work. But it will take some effort to get used to :)

Comment: I will say again, though, that I predict at some point down the road trouble having only long-lived branches for your stages/environments. But I will let you do your own experiences and hopefully prove me wrong ;) Also, I must emphasize the importance of cherry-pick merging (instead of normal 3-point or ff merging). The risk is obviously, that a "normal" merge will merge any deltas in the feature-branch into the release-branch - no matter if the change was introduced in the branch or before branch creation (e.g. in develop). Let me know, how it all works out, it's an interesting case :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick reponse. I already heard about cherry-pick. As you told, it is kinda tricky..I will try to setting up the branches and do the normal merge..I will give a try and let you know if any concerns. Thanks again Frederik :)

Comment: My issues with release branch, ideally for my project, once we create a release branch and do the build from the release branch , this build go up to production deployment, if build is working. so in this case what time we should merge this release branch to master branch? if i update the master branch from release branch after production deployment in this case there is there is risk, as production deployment from release branch. i don't see any benefit to have master branch.this is extra burden for release manager, to update the master branch, i think multiple release branches make sense.

Comment: @GautamSharma In my project we have the same case. We merge in master after the deploy in production of the release. Yes, it's an effort to mantain the master, but at least we always have a simple branch that reflect the situation in production.
Very useful when you have to answer the question: "which version of the software I have currently installed?"

Answer (score 2):

Look at these "Git flow for Scrum" articles: https://www.stenusys.com/scrum-branching-strategy/ and https://markshust.com/2018/04/07/introducing-git-ship-simplified-git-flow-workflow/

[image]

[image]